# Create symbolic link recursively, if file 1.JPG exists rename it to 1A.JPG

Tags: shell-script, symlink, recursive

I have a shell script for creating symbolic links of all my photos from one year. The photos are from different cameras and are in subdirectories.

```
f=$(pwd);
export f;
q="2015/";
z="2015_Links/";
find $q/. \( -name "*.CR2" -o -name "*.JPG" \) -execdir sh -c 'ln -s "$PWD"/$(basename {}) "$f"/"$z"/Link_$(basename {})' {} \;
```

Some of the photos have the same filename, causing the error:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘2015_Links/Link_IMG_1588.CR2’: File exists
```

In this case I would like to rename those existing files. For example, `Link_IMG_1588.CR2` to `Link_IMG_1588A.CR2`.

Answer (score 1):

I've found another solution for the problem.

I managed to rename my photos (with `find` and `exiv2`) from my different cameras so that every filename is unique (IMG number + Date):

```
find 2015/. \( -name "*.CR2" -o -name "*.JPG" \) -execdir sh -c 'exiv2 -r':basename:_%Y%m%d_%H_%M_%S' rename $(basename {})' {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Strategy:

- Test if the ideal target file name exists.
- If it does, try adding numerical suffixes `-1`, `-2`, etc.

Additional improvements:

- Use `-exec … {} +` instead of `-execdir … {} \;` for a slight performance improvement. You don't actually need `-execdir` here since you're making absolute links.
- Use `$x` (or `$1` if you stick to `… {} \;`) instead of `{}` in the inner shell. Never use `{}` inside a shell snippet on `find -exec`: that inserts the file name directly into the shell script, so it's parsed as shell syntax, which breaks down if the file name contains any character that has a special meaning in shell syntax. Always pass `{}` as a separate parameter.

Code (untested):

```
find "$q/." \( -name "*.CR2" -o -name "*.JPG" \) -exec sh -c '
    for x; do
      base=$0/Link_${x##*/}; base=${base%.*}; ext=${x##*.}
      if [ -e "$target.$ext" ]; then
        suffix=1;
        while [ -e "${base}-$suffix.$ext"; do suffix=$((suffix+1)); done
      fi
      ln -s -- "$PWD/${x##*/}" "$target"
    done
  ' "$PWD/$z" {} +
```